# Will VPN help to restrict Meterpreter session?

Tags: vpn, meterpreter

I'm a victim of Meterpreter attack. I'm now using VPN in all the devices. My question is, will it help me to restrict meterpreter attack?

If not, what is the way out to get rid of meterpreter attack?

Comment: What is a "meterpreter attack" and how do you know you are a victim? If the exploit uses a reverse connection, then no, a VPN will do nothing.

Comment: I'm confirmed I'm a victim. I scanned with https://github.com/rvazarkar/antipwny and found my chrome and messenger are infected. I have also just confirmed VPN does not restrict. Could you please tell how to detect that in MAC/ iPhone? How to get rid of this?